# Read a hadoop sequential File format without hadoop jars

Tags: java, sequential

Do we have a way where we can read hadoop sequentialFile format without hadoop jars?

Reason behind this question:
I am using HDFS as staging environment to keep appending to a existing file which is of type Octet-Stream and writing as sequentialFile format. But When I am reading, I want to read it as normal binaryStream without using hadoop jars.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you want to access sequentialinputformat of hadoop then you need to have hadoop jar because sequentialinputformat extends inputformat interface and this inputformat interface is defined in hadoop jar.

If you want to use binary stream then use serialization in java. Even the sequentialinputformat in hadoop is a result of inspiration from serialization in java and they almost work in same way too. So it would be better if you can use serialization and deseralisation feature of java.